# Wordpress: how to send user details to external db after registering

Tags: php, wordpress

When a user registers on a Wordpress site, am trying to use the 'user_register' hook so that I can grab the user's details and insert it into a separate external database. I have similar code working in woocommerce when an order is created, but I can't figure out why it will not insert the user data. I've left the original query/connection attempts as well, for illustrative purpose. The code is in the functions.php

```
function save_user_to_externaldb( $user_id ) { 
 global $wpdb;
 $user = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID='$user_id'", ARRAY_A); 
 // external db connection attempt
 $db = new wpdb('db', 'pass', 'user', 'localhost');
 if ($db) 
 {
  // original query  
  //$status = $db->query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,status,firstname,lastname) VALUES (".$user['user_login'].",".$user['user_pass'].",".$user['user_email'].",'5', ".$lastname.",".$firstname."')");   
  // current query
  $status = $db->query('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES ("$user[\'user_login\'],"$user[\'user_pass\']","$user[\'user_email\'])"');       
  }
  else
  {
   $db->show_errors();
  }
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'save_user_to_externaldb', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but I had a simular problem. 
I think you can not user $wpdb->get_row inside the user_register hook. 
When I changed my code from:
**$wpdb->get_row("select**
To:
**$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT**

all worked fine. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: That's actually a great idea - I will try and give you an update if it works. Thanks!